# Is there any console tool to save some commands as bookmarks or buttons?

Tags: console, terminal

I work often with ssh and command line scripts. I would like not to type the name of the command with arguments again and again and also to call my scripts by clicking a button.

Is there any console application that does that?

My guess is that I should fork a console tool (like konsole) and then add buttons that can be associated with commands I want to use often.

Answer (score -1):

Then the better option is creating a desktop launcher , like the following as target.
Assuming you are having a gnome desktop.
Execute the following command,
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
This will launch a window  ,which will prompt for a command name , command ,and comments.
Fill it as per your needs,
Eg: name : MyCommand_to_start_apache
command : httpd -f /my/custom/httpd.conf

That's it , if you want more fun give a try for gnome-panel or gnome-tweak-tool.

Another great tool is [AutoKey](http://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/autokey-linux-utility-for-text-substitution-hotkeys-and-desktop-automation/)

Comment: Nope, I want a visual tool with buttons! I don't want to type just click!